# ngIf an angular reactive form component value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a set of radio buttons. If a user selected the value "yes" I want to show an additional box on the form.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bgahw?file=src/app/personal/personal.component.ts

**HTML.component**

```
<div formGroupName="radioButtonsGroup" class="form-group col-6 pl-0 pt-3">

    <div class="form-check-inline" *ngFor="let item of personal.radioButtonsdata">
        <label for="{{item.section}}" class="col-12 customradio"
            ><span>{{item.section}}</span>
            <input [value]="item" id="{{item.section}}" type="radio" formControlName="selectedButton"/>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-md-8" *ngIf="selectedButton.control.item === 'yes'"> --> //my attempt to target above input value
  <div class="col-md-8" >
        <input type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
</div>
    </div>
```

Can anybody get this to work and show me what I am doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access the value of the form control:

```
*ngIf="form.get('radioButtonsGroup.selectedButton').value.section === 'yes'">
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmupp3?file=src/app/personal/personal.component.html)**

Comment: In Angular 8 this does not work. We need to change it as below, `*ngIf="radioButtonGroup.get("selectedButton").value === "yes"`

Comment: @Pinka Yes, that is how you get the value of a formcontrol that has a **primitive** value, but OP has an **OBJECT** value for the form control, which includes a property named "section", so we need to dig into the nested object in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Everything you write in the template is resolved against the corresponding class (or against template variables), so you have to refer to the JavaScript control like this:

```
*ngIf="form.controls['selectedButton'].value === 'yes'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a function to set flag based on value of the radio button, `(ngModelChange)="onRadiochange($event)"`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqzpwk)**

.html

```
<input [value]="item" (ngModelChange)="onRadiochange($event)" id="{{item.section}}" type="radio" formControlName="selectedButton" />

<div class="col-md-8" *ngIf="showTitle">
        <input type="text" formControlName="title"   class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
</div>
```

.ts

```
  onRadiochange(e) {
    if(e.section == 'yes'){
      this.showTitle = true
    } else {
      this.showTitle = false
    }
  }
```

It can also be done in one line like this:

```
<input [value]="item" (ngModelChange)="$event.section == 'yes' ? showTitle=true:showTitle=false" id="{{item.section}}" type="radio" formControlName="selectedButton" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever **yes** checkbox is selected, you have to display the title textbox.

In that case, change your code like this.

In **personal.component.ts**, add this variable.

```
yesSelected: boolean = true;
```

Also in ngOnInit(),

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
      if(val.radioButtonsGroup.selectedButton.section === "yes") 
         this.yesSelected = true;
      else 
         this.yesSelected = false;
});
```

In **personal.component.html**, rewrite your if condition like this.

```
<div class="col-md-8" *ngIf="yesSelected">
      <input type="text" formControlName="title" placeholder="Title">
</div>
```

**These changes will show the title textbox only when the yes check box is selected.**